# Pygame snake as first game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, snake-game

After poking around in some areas of python, I've decided to try Pygame. After about two hours of coding, this is what I came up with:

```
import pygame
import time
import random
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

WINDOW = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption('snake')

FOOD_COORS = []

TICK = 15


RUN = True
SNAKE_COMP = [[50, 50, 2], [40, 50, 2], [30, 50, 2], [20, 50, 2], [10, 50, 2]]
f = [random.randint(0, 50)*10, random.randint(0, 50)*10]
d = 2
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

def hit():
    time.sleep(3)
    pygame.quit()

class snake():
    def __init__(self, SNAKE_COMP):
        self.x, self.y = SNAKE_COMP[0][0:2]
    def draw(self, SNAKE_COMP):
        self.SNAKE_COMP = SNAKE_COMP
        for i in range(0, len(SNAKE_COMP)):
            pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, (255, 255, 255), (SNAKE_COMP[i][0], SNAKE_COMP[i][1], 10, 10))

    def hit_check(self, SNAKE_COMP):
        self.SNAKE_COMP = SNAKE_COMP
        if SNAKE_COMP[0][0] >= 500 or SNAKE_COMP[0][0] < 0:
            hit()
        if SNAKE_COMP[0][1] >= 500 or SNAKE_COMP[0][1] < 0:
            hit()
        test_l = [[]]
        for i in range(0, len(SNAKE_COMP)):
            test_l.append(tuple(SNAKE_COMP[i][0:2]))
        for i in range(0, len(test_l)):
            if test_l.count(test_l[i]) > 1:
                hit()

class food():
    global FOOD_COORS
    def draw(self):
        x, y = self.x, self.y
        pygame.draw.rect(WINDOW, (255, 255, 255), (x, y, 10, 10))
    def spawn(self, SNAKE_COMP):
        global FOOD_COORS
        self.SNAKE_COMP = SNAKE_COMP
        test_l = [[]]
        for i in range(0, len(SNAKE_COMP)):
            test_l.append(SNAKE_COMP[i][0:2])
        g = True
        while g:
            x = random.randint(0, 49)*10
            y = random.randint(0, 49)*10
            if [x, y] not in test_l:
                g = False
        FOOD_COORS = [x, y]
        self.x, self.y = x, y
snek = snake(SNAKE_COMP)
apple = food()
apple.spawn(SNAKE_COMP)
s = False
g = False
while RUN:
    CLOCK.tick(TICK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            RUN = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and d != 3:
        d = 1
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and d != 4:
        d = 2
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and d != 1:
        d = 3
    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and d != 2:
        d = 4
    if g != True and SNAKE_COMP[0][0:2] != FOOD_COORS:
        last = len(SNAKE_COMP) - 1
        for i in range(1, len(SNAKE_COMP)):
            SNAKE_COMP[len(SNAKE_COMP)-i][2] = SNAKE_COMP[len(SNAKE_COMP)-i-1][2]
        SNAKE_COMP[0][2] = d
        for i in range(0, len(SNAKE_COMP)):
            if SNAKE_COMP[i][2] == 1:
                SNAKE_COMP[i][1] -= 10
            elif SNAKE_COMP[i][2] == 2:
                SNAKE_COMP[i][0] += 10
            elif SNAKE_COMP[i][2] == 3:
                SNAKE_COMP[i][1] += 10
            elif SNAKE_COMP[i][2] == 4:
                SNAKE_COMP[i][0] -= 10
    else:
        k = SNAKE_COMP[0][2]
        FOOD_COORS.append(k)
        if k == 1:
            FOOD_COORS[1] -= 10
        elif k == 2:
            FOOD_COORS[0] += 10
        elif k == 3:
            FOOD_COORS[1] += 10
        elif k == 4:
            FOOD_COORS[0] -= 10
        SNAKE_COMP.insert(0, FOOD_COORS)
        apple.spawn(SNAKE_COMP)
    snek.hit_check(SNAKE_COMP)
    apple.draw()
    snek.draw(SNAKE_COMP)
    pygame.display.update()
    WINDOW.fill((0, 0, 0))

pygame.quit()
```

I definitely thinks this can be improved, just not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really todo with the code, but, it's always a good idea to add comments to your code to make it more readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1):

- The names of classes should be in CamelCase instead of snake_case.
  The class names `snake` and `food` should be capitalized.
- Argument names should be in lowercase.
  `SNAKE_COMP` can be changed to `snake_comp` or something similar to that.
- You should not instance attributes outside of `__init__`.
  `self.SNAKE_COMP` should be declared inside `__init__` or should be removed completely, since it's not being used at all in either of the classes.
- You don't need parenthesis after a class name unless you are inheriting from another class.
  `Snake()` and `Food()` should just be `Snake` and `Food` respectively
- As @JamesRobinson correctly said so, add comments to the ambiguous parts of your code so the readers will be able to understand what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names are not good.

What is `f`?  What is `d`?  What does `SNAKE_COMP` even mean? I understand the first two values in it to be coordinates, but what is the third, and since it's always 2, why is it not a constant?

What does `hit` mean? Hitting the wall? Hitting food? Hitting another snake? Collision is another common term which is a bit more clear.

What is `FOOD_COORS`? Is it supposed to be COOR**D**S ?

I guess `d` is direction. Then name it `direction`. And use names for the directions, don't call them 1, 2, 3, 4.

If you make the code readable, it increases the chance that others will take time to read it and give feedback.